# More than 8 hours and Android Studio is still not finished building my app (w/ Proguard-minify on)

Tags: android, gradle, build, proguard

I expected the build to take a significant amount of time but not as long as it is now. It's already past 8 hrs (9PM - 6AM) after I began but it's still not finished.

Details:

- My PC is relatively powerful (built for gaming)
- I extensively use external libraries, here they are:

Code:

```
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'org.adw.library:discrete-seekbar:1.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:23.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
compile 'com.flipboard:bottomsheet-core:1.5.0'
compile 'com.flipboard:bottomsheet-commons:1.5.0'
compile 'com.guerwan:transitionbackport:1.1'
compile 'com.nhaarman.listviewanimations:lib-manipulation:3.1.0@aar'
compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
compile 'com.ogaclejapan.smarttablayout:library:1.6.0@aar'
compile 'com.github.traex.rippleeffect:library:1.3'
compile 'asia.ivity.android:drag-sort-listview:1.0'
compile 'org.adw.library:discrete-seekbar:1.0.0'
compile 'com.liulishuo.filedownloader:library:0.1.9'
compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'
compile 'com.github.castorflex.smoothprogressbar:library:1.0.1-SNAPSHOT@aar'
compile 'org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0'
```

QUESTION:

Why is that the case? Is there anyway to minimize it? Or is it even normal not a bug? Thanks.

Comment: that is not normal.  are you on a slow connection? tried restarting Android Studio?

Comment: My DL speed on average is 2-3 Mbps, and UL of 0.4 - 0.7 Mbps. Is that slow?

Comment: shouldn't be I just was wondering if with all your dependencies,it would take a while to download these 3rd party libraries.  Did anything work? the build should take a few minutes depending on the specs of the comp.. what are yours?

Comment: I don't think internet speed is an issue, I can easily download GB's of files in just a day.

Comment: I got core i5 as CPU, 6GB RAM, and plenty of storage space.

Comment: so it literally just sits there all day and says "building" try and run a gradle build with logging through the command prompt. at least then you can see which of these libraries is having the issues.

Comment: Precisely. So I decided to cancel it instead and turn off minify.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this happen a few times in the past, especially when on a flaky internet connection. Here's what I would try:

1. Force close Android Studio and re-launch.
2. Enabled Gradle Offline Work (assuming you have cached versions of your dependencies) by going to File->Settings->Build,Execution,Deployment->Build Tools->Gradle and then check "Offline Work"
3. Generate your .apk

If you still are having problems building after that, I would try File->Invalidate Caches and Restart. Do you also have this issue when generating .apks with with ProGuard disabled?

Comment: How do I cache the dependencies? Thanks.

Comment: They are cached automatically every time you sync your Gradle build. That way if for whatever reason you need to work offline you can still build without an internet connection.